# Правильная реализация подсчета даты

Tags: c#, дата

В моей игре есть подарки, которые можно открыть по истечении N промежутка времени. В основном от 2 до 8 часов. При получении подарка персонажу я `Ticks` сохраняю в специальный список моделей этих самых подарков. Когда игрок выходит с игры, этот самый тик сохраняется в базу данных. При входе в игру, высчитывается разница и показывает результат оставшегося времени. Этот простой алгоритм работает, если зайти в игру через 1-3е часов. Но если зайти в игру в следующий день, то расчет времени сходит с ума. Он может показать и 120 часов осталось. А может и 30 минут осталось, хотя прошло уже больше 10 часов. Как можно избавиться от этого бага?

Код, где добавляется подарок:

```
PresentContract presentContract = new PresentContract();

presentContract.PresentType = battleResultSource.PresentType;
presentContract.ObjId = ObjId;
presentContract.Time = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(HowManySecondsWillFirstLevelOpeningGift).Ticks;
presentContract.Slot = InternalDetermineFreeSlot(GameClientField.PresentContracts);
presentContract.CostOfOneSecondGift = CharacterConfig.CostOfOneSecondGift;

GameClientField.PresentContracts[presentContract.Slot] = presentContract;
```

Код, где вычисляется разница между настоящим временем и временем возможности открытия подарка:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(presentContracts.Time);
_presentModels[presentContracts.Slot]._dateTime = dateTime; 
TimeSpan timeSpan = _presentModels[presentContracts.Slot]._dateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Где это считается? `_dateTime`

Comment: @tym32167 извините, забыл написать. Сейчас сделаю исправление...

Comment: @tym32167 а возможно ли, что я отнимаю дату от меньшего к большему? Ведь я тестировал только когда отнимаю от большого малого.

Comment: К чему эти сложности? Почему бы просто не написать сюда presentContract.Time текущее время, потом когда юзер переоткрывает приложение, то глядеть (текущее время минус сохраненные время) > ваш интервал  HowManySecondsWillFirstLevelOpeningGift

Comment: Ну и я бы не советовал юзать DateTime.Now. Пользуйтесь DateTime.UtcNow, если не хотите огрести от временных зон.

Comment: @tym32167 уже делал. Тот же эффект.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148732/discussion-between-alexey-and-tym32167).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, пытаться вычислить сумму тиков - не лучшая идея. Сохраняйте в базу данных текущее время и считайте разницу. Лучше использовать UTC время. Убедитесь, что после сохранения и извлечения времени из базы данных, часовой пояс и timestamp времени не изменился. Убедитесь также, что время генерируется сервером, а не отправляется игроком, так вы избежите проблем с недобросовестными игроками. Кроме того, учитывайте, что `Ticks` является `long` (`Int64`) и может вызывать проблемы во время явного сужающего преобразования типов.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
// user logout...
// save 'start' to DB
// wait...
// user logged
// load 'start' from DB

long elapsedTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - start.Ticks;
TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(elapsedTicks);

if (elapsedSpan >= yourCooldownSpan)
{
    // your logic
}
```

Выбирайте задержку также UTC timezone.

Comment: А зачем этот фокус с Ticks'ами? `elapsedSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - start`

Comment: гпт-бейзед ансвер?

Comment: @Anatol нет, сам писал. Причём с телефона. Посмотри историю изменений, я ошибку исправил в коде на следующий день. Просто недавно познал тайну координации времени на JS и Python в своём проекте.